# AngularJS $http.get with resolve

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting to know AngularJS and I have an interesting problem. I'm getting to know the routeProvider and I thought I could write my app like if you search a table name, it'll change the route, so you can write the table right after the url, too.

**Details from app.js**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/index.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/tables/:table', {
            templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
            controller: 'aboutCtrl',
            resolve: {
                tables: function($http, $routeParams){
                    return $http.get('http://mywebsite.com/doc/ajax/table.php?function=get_table_data&table='+$routeParams.table)
                                .then(function(response){
                                    console.log($routeParams.table);
                                    return response.data;
                                })
                }
            }
        })

        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'pages/404.html'
        })
});
```

**The controller**

```
angular
    .module('testApp')
    .controller('aboutCtrl',function($scope, tables){

        $scope.title = "This is the about page!";

        // declare helper variables to not use
        // $scope inside a loop
        var rawFields = [];
        var titleNames = [];

        // load the thead titles (keys)
        angular.forEach(tables[1], function(value, key){
            titleNames.push(key);
        });

        // load table datas without the first object that
        // contains other informations
        for (var i=1; i<tables.length;i++) {
            rawFields.push(tables[i]);
        };

        // set $scope variables to use them in the HTML
        $scope.fields = rawFields;
        $scope.tableName = tables[0].TableName;
        $scope.titles = titleNames;
    });
```

Basically that's all you need, but I can include more code if you want.

When I use in the **$http.get** `...function=get_table_data&table=teszt` or `...function=get_table_data&table=teszt2` (now these two are available) everything is working perfectly, I get the datas and I can do anything with them

**BUT** if I try the version I included above `$http.get('http://mywebsite.com/doc/ajax/table.php?function=get_table_data&table='+$routeParams.table)`, that's working strange. If I type `...#/tables/teszt` I don't get the datas, but if I write after `...#/tables/teszt2`, I get the `teszt` table's data and if I write something else after instead of `teszt2` then I get the `teszt2` table's data.

**How could I use urls to make ajax calls?**

I would appreciate any best practices if you would do it in a different way.

Comment: A missing `$scope.apply()` maybe ?

Comment: I don't know, as I'm not an expert yet I'm going to look for how to use it. Thanks the tip!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [$routeParams docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams):

> Note that the **$routeParams are only updated after a route change completes successfully**. This means that **you cannot rely on $routeParams being correct in route resolve functions**. Instead you can use $route.current.params to access the new route's parameters.

So just inject `$route` instead of `$routeParams`:

```
resolve: {
    tables: function($http, $route){
      return $http.get('http://mywebsite.com/doc/ajax/table.php?function=get_table_data&table='+$route.current.params.table)
      .then(function(response){
        return response.data;
      })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tables: function($http, $routeParams, $rootScope){
                var promise = $http.get('http://mywebsite.com/doc/ajax/table.php?function=get_table_data&table='+$routeParams.table)
                            .then(function(response){
                                console.log($routeParams.table);
                                return response.data;
                            });
                if($rootScope.$$phase != '$apply' && $rootScope.$$phase != '$digest') {
                                    $rootScope.$apply();
                }
                return promise;
            }
```

Comment: :/ Same issue occurs. Only binds the data after changing the url.