# angular js , ng-model not ready for third party directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jstree

I am using https://github.com/ezraroi/ngJsTree and I have come across the following problem.

My ng-model is a AJAX request and when my controller fires, data is not yet ready, so it does not render anything.

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <div js-tree="treeConfig" ng-model="treeData" should-apply="ignoreModelChanges()" tree="treeInstance" tree-events="ready:readyCB;create_node:createNodeCB"></div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/IRaqvd0DPcqkxgo0xoqa?p=preview

Comment: if you are using `$http` for your server calls, the directive should update properly when the response returns.  perhaps your problem is with the way your service calls are happening.  Showing that code would help focus the problem a bit to find a solution.

Comment: also, `ignoreModelChanges()` seems an odd thing to pair with an `$http` request where the model will definitely change;  have you tried to see if it works when this is removed?

Comment: here is my pluker https://plnkr.co/edit/fCrupsxDMprHdLCocZIe?p=preview

Comment: your problem seems to be due to your scripts not loading properly.  See the console errors:  "Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vakata/jstree/master/dist/jstree.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."  GitHub does not support linking `raw` scripts directly.

Comment: i updated my pluker https://plnkr.co/edit/IRaqvd0DPcqkxgo0xoqa?p=preview

Comment: your plunker was missing an `ng-app` declaration, it wasn't even bootstrapping.

Comment: added it , but still same result

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your application, you may have a few alternatives to handle this situation. Create a service that is responsible for reading the data. Then you can do one of the following:

1. make router to wait till the reading is resolved before
   navigating to the view. Here is a related SO question: [AngularJS $http.get with resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309661/angularjs-http-get-with-resolve)
2. add event listener to the controller and
   make service to emit/broadcast event when the data is ready.

In both cases, you may want to read data from service.

Comment: any example of bulltet 1 and 2?

Comment: added a link to the SO question about resolving the data in the routeProvider. As for 2nd example - I'd go for angular documentation but there is also related SO question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14502006/working-with-scope-emit-and-on)